# To what extent does mod_suexec interact with Passenger?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, phusion-passenger, cgi

On a shared server (specifically a DreamHost shared server running Debian, but I don't know if this matters) with mod_suexec activated and with PHP and Python forced to use CGI or FastCGI, would you expect Passenger processes to be run as the Apache user or as the user from whose home directory the Passenger-powered app is run?

Please explain the basis for your answer.

(I'm guessing the latter, for consistency with DreamHost's approach to PHP and Python, but I'm vague on how Passenger interacts with Apache, let alone with mod_suexec.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_suexec` is specific to CGI setups, which a completely different technology from passenger.

Passenger implements its own way of user switching. The user applications are run as is determined broadly according to the following:

1. If we are a Rails app, run as the owner of `config/environment.rb`. If we are a Rack app, run as the owner of `config.ru`.
2. If the determined user would be `root`, use the configured `PassengerDefaultUser`
3. If this still would be `root` (or unconfigured), run as the user, Apache runs at (e.g. `wwwrun` or `www-data`).

For more information, see http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching